# Jenkins pipeline: No such DSL method 'jobDsl' found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to do a **`seed`** pipeline job, to pull all the DSLs from the `scripts` directory and generate the jobs in return. This is what I got, as my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  
  stages {
    stage('seed_or_update_jobs') {
      steps {
        jobDsl(
          targets: ['scripts/*.groovy'].join('\n'),
          removedJobAction: 'DELETE',
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but keep getting:

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'jobDsl' found among
> stepes [ ... ]**

All the references (in the web) seem to be pointing to the same syntax as above, but not working for me. Can anyone tell me what am I missing or doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-San

Comment: Do you have the Job DSL Plugin installed?

Comment: The correct usage of the plugin can be found here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/job-dsl/

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell, if i go the _Manage Jenkins_ > _Managed Plugins_ > _Installed_, I see `job-dsl`is listed there, so it seems to be there.

Comment: Having said that though, I just noticed if I go for a _Freestyle Project_, I don't see `Process Job DSLs` under the _Build_ > _Add Build Steps_ dropdown list - does it mean it not installed properly?